# How can I identify to which quest line a specific quest belongs

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My Journal is Full of Quests, And I would like to know if their is a way to determine  if a quest belongs to the Main Quest line, or to one of the factions instead of the other questions

Basically: how to determine if a single quest belongs to the:

- Main Quest
- Bards College
- College of Winterhold
- Companions
- Dark Brotherhood
- Imperial Legion
- Stormcloaks
- Thieves Guild

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can tell by looking at the symbol next to the quests name when viewing it in your quest log.

[image: Symbols!]

The Bards College does not have a symbol of it's own, but instead uses the generic Side Quest icon.

**Main Quest**
[image: Main Quest = Dragons!]

**Side Quests**
[image: Side Quests!]

**College of Winterhold**
[image: Eyes for Mages!]

**Thieves Guild**
[image: Keys for Thieves]

**Dark Brotherhood**
[image: Hail Sithis!]

**The Companions**
[image: Werewolves!]

**Civil War**
[image: Civil War, different icon on either side!]
*This icon is shared between the Stormcloak and Imperial sides. It is the only asymmetrical item in this list.*

**Daedric Quests**
[image: Oblivion!]

Comment: +1, freehand circle (or at least it's probably a circle...not gonna lie, pretty bad)

Comment: @NickT: It's an *awful* freehand circle. I'm not good at the things to begin with and I'm using a lousy trackpad at the moment besides.

Comment: +1 for the clear description and MS Paint masterpiece. Also, FWIW, the Bards College is more like a pretty nice sidequest (for the training benefits from the professors) than a proper guild questline. There's only one quest to become a bard, then 3 more fetch-an-item quests for skill-ups. So it makes sense that it doesn't have its own icon, IMO.

Comment: @Bryan And the fetch-an-item quests aren't actually quests at all, just "Miscellaneous Objectives", so there really is only one Bard's College quest.

Comment: I only mention the Bard's college because it was explicitly asked about.

Comment: I had not noticed this, excellent answer.