# New quests aren't updating?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have gotten to the point in the main story where I have completed 'Battle for Solitude'. I have completed everything else up to this point except misc. missions I have yet to discover.

I want to continue with the main story line, but any quests for the main story line are not updating. I don't know if I am supposed to go speak with someone, I've tried talking with every Jarl to see if that will start up something. Nothing seems to be working.

I'm 51% complete with the game right now so I know there is more to the story.

How can I start the next set of quests?

Comment: Battle for Solitude doesn't really have anything to do with main story. Main story is the dragon killing jig. Everything else is basically misc quests, though which ones you have missed will depend on which ones you did.

Comment: Where are you with regards to Alduin?  You are the Dragonborn afterall.  Your primary business is with the dragons.

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot of your quest log, misc. section included, we could tell you your next most important quest. If you feel you have finished the main quest line, consider where you are in each of the [faction quest lines](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests)

Comment: Check out https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40273/how-can-i-identify-to-which-quest-line-a-specific-quest-belongs .  It will help you identify which of your quests is part of the "Main" quest line.  If you want to also see the icons for DLC, check out http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests

Comment: There is no way of finding a solution with the information provided. As alluded to in the comments, the main story's quest-line has a dragon-related branch in addition to the Civil War branch, the latter of which 'Battle for Solitude' is a part of. At the very least we'll need to know the last dragon-related quest mentioned in the OP's journal.

Answer (score -1):

The 'Battle for Solitude' is the last quest in the Stormcloak Civil War questline, so it has nothing to do with the main questline. The last quest in the main questline is the Alduin battle (the epilogue comes after, but you only have to stand in one spot and do nothing). Any quests after that you will have to find. If you specify which quest in the main story you need help with, I can help you. I recommend [the wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Skyrim) for advice.